# How to calculate 'sqrt' of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a 3x3 matrix A, and A=B*B. B is also a 3x3 matrix. A is known, and B is unknown. How can I calculate B?
Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know either, so I googled it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix

Comment: By `B*B`, do you mean the product of B and B, or of B* and B (where B* is the conjugate transpose of B)?

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly, not very easily. Because $A=B^*B$, you have that $A$ can be unitarily diagonalizable: $A=UDU^*$, with $U$ unitary and $D$ diagonal. The diagonal of $D$ contains the eigenvalues of $A$ (counting multiplicities); these are all non-negative.

Then you can take $E$ to be the diagonal matrix where $E_{jj}=D_{jj}^{1/2}$. Then $E^2=D$, and $$(UEU^*)^2=UE^2U^*=UDU^*=A.$$

If you want to make this explicit you need to find the three eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ of $A$ and unit eigenvectors for each, $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Then $U$ is the matrix with columns $v_1,v_2,v_3$.